# Sorting Get-ADUser output by password expiry date

Tags: powershell, sorting, active-directory

I am running a powershell script to get AD users and their password expiration date. I would like to sort the output based on their password expiration date.

Here is the script:

```cs
Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False} `
           -Properties "DisplayName", "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" |
  Select-Object -Property "Displayname", @{
                                            Name="ExpiryDate";
                                            Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}
                                          } > result.txt
```

How can I sort/display the result by the `ExpiryDate` field?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-5.1

Answer (score 4):

Use the [sort-object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-5.1) cmdlet on the `Get-ADUser` output like this:

`| Sort-Object -property ExpiryDate`

So the whole thing would look like this:

```cs
Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False} `
           -Properties "DisplayName", "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" | 
    Select-Object -Property "Displayname", @{
                                               Name="ExpiryDate";
                                               Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}
                                             } | 
    Sort-Object -property ExpiryDate > result.txt
```